# Uninstalling broadcom-wl driver: Now stuck in emergency mode

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I have fedora.
I installed incompatible drivers: "`sudo dnf install broadcom-wl`" and restarted linux. Now i am stuck in emergency mode with shell

I tried removing driver module, but for some reason, lsmod | grep wl does not sees this module, so i can not remove it, hence i am stuck in emergency mode. Please help

**EDIT:**

Here are [systemctl logs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDiCFSAUdKc)

I tried grepping other names related to broadcom:
"`bcm43xx, ssb, b43, ndiswrapper, bcma, broadcom, wl`", did not find anything

Comment: I would try to get the full list of modules instead of grepping wl perhaps it's called broadcomxxx

Comment: @admstg Thank you for your reply, i updated the question

Comment: Boot into recovery, run `dnf remove broadcom-wl`, type `reboot`.

Comment: Note the black-on-white-background `>` characters in the right-most column of the screen on some lines. Those indicate that the log lines continue further than is displayed, and you would need to press the right arrow key to view the rest of those lines. Since `dracut` is mentioned, the system is still in initramfs phase, and the message `timeout, still waiting for fol>` suggests it's waiting for some device to appear, but since the video won't show the ends of the lines, it's impossible to see which device(s) it's waiting for. The next lines seem to suggest it's waiting for some disk device.

Comment: Try to start live linux from memory stick - this will allow you to view and manipulate files in filesystem easily. This may help you to find something. [Slax](https://www.slax.org/) is my personal choice as it contains lots of useful and user friendly tools but any should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing driver by "`dnf remove broadcom-wl`" and then doing "`dracut --regenerate-all`" did not seem to do anything.

Fixed it by simply chrooting into os from live cd and restoring my timeshift snapshot, sorry.